# Mockito can not mock Random in Java 17

Tags: java, mockito, java-17

Trying to update my project from Java 11 to Java 17 and got an unexpected error from Mockito in a specific test.

```
mock(java.util.Random.class);
```

Throws

```
Feb 04, 2022 3:07:01 PM com.google.inject.internal.MessageProcessor visit
INFO: An exception was caught and reported. Message: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class 
    net.bytebuddy.description.annotation.AnnotationDescription$ForLoadedAnnotation cannot access interface
    jdk.internal.util.random.RandomSupport$RandomGeneratorProperties (in module java.base) 
    because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.util.random to unnamed module @2f54a33d
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class java.util.Random.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 17
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 17.0.2+8-86
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 17.0.2+8-86
JVM info           : mixed mode, sharing
OS name            : Mac OS X
OS version         : 12.1
```

Not sure why Mockito is failing on this test.

Comment: _"please report to the mailing list"_ -- I think you might get better help over there.

Comment: What are you trying to mock, exactly? If you need an exact number, then rewrite the tests... Don't pass around an instance of `Random`

Comment: Maybe you can check this [conversation](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/34355).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue here is mockito (via ByteBuddy) is trying to use an inaccessible type at runtime (via reflection). From Java 9 onwards, not all modules are accessible unless you explicitly export/open them.

As this is a runtime issue, you can add `--add-opens` as a JVM arg/CLI option to make this type accessible.

As per the Oracle guide [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-12F945EB-71D6-46AF-8C3D-D354FD0B1781), `--add-opens` does the following.

> If you have to allow code on the classpath to do deep reflection to
> access nonpublic members, then use the --add-opens runtime option.

If you want to export internal types available in compile time as well, you can use `--add-exports`.

To solve your specific issue; use the following.

`--add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.util.random=ALL-UNNAMED`.

`ALL-UNNAMED` means, a specified package is available in the entire codebase.

However, mocking types that don't belong to you is not a good practice. Maybe, you can simplify this if there's an alternative.

Comment: `mock(Random.class, withSettings().withoutAnnotations())` also worked for me

Comment: I see, that looks simple and inline on the code.

Comment: [`ALL-UNNAMED` is "code on the classpath"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/migrate/migrating-jdk-8-later-jdk-releases.html#GUID-2F61F3A9-0979-46A4-8B49-325BA0EE8B66), if the code were on the module path, you would use the module name instead of `ALL-UNNAMED`.

Answer (score 9):

This particular issue was also resolvable using:

```
mock(SecureRandom.class, withSettings().withoutAnnotations())
```

Answer (score 4):

upgrade mokito to 4.4.0 it worked

Answer (score 0):

Needing to mock Random indicates that your code hasn't been written to be testable. Do something like this:

```java
   interface RandomSource {
        /**
         * Return a random number that matches the criteria you need
         */
        int nextNumber();
    }

    @Bean
    class DefaultRandomSource implements RandomSource {
        private final Random r = new Random();
        public int nextNumber() {
            return r.nextInt(2);
        }
    }
    
    @Bean
    class ClassToTest {
        private final RandomSource randomSource;

        @Autowired
        public ClassToTest(RandomSource randomSource) {
            this.randomSource = randomSource;
        }

        public String doSomething() {
            return randomSource.nextNumber() == 0 ? "Foo" : "Bar";
        }
    }
    
    @Test
    void testDoSomething() {
        RandomSource r = mock(RandomSource.class);
        when(r.nextNumber()).thenReturn(0);
        ClassToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest(r);
        assertEquals("Foo", classToTest.doSomething());
    }
```

Comment: I dont believe mocking a proxy object is fundamentally much better than mocking the original core object

Comment: There are worse things to mock than `Random`, true.

Comment: Obviously, there is no need to mock an interface, as you can simply *implement* the interface in the way you need.

Comment: Another point worth noting is that such an interface does already exist in JDK 17, [`RandomGenerator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html). When you accept `RandomGenerator` as input, you don’t need to implement a wrapper around `Random` because it does already implement the interface. And you can “mock” it by simply implementing one method, `nextLong()`. For example `RandomGenerator g = () -> 0L;  g.longs(5).forEach(System.out::println); return g.nextBoolean()? "Foo": "Bar";`