# Mockito Error in Spring Boot Tests - Cannot mock this class

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I have written a simple test using mockito in spring-boot framework. However running the test throws the below error.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Unable to initialize @Spy annotated field 'random'.

Mockito cannot mock this class: class java.util.Random.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 17
JVM vendor name    : Azul Systems, Inc.
JVM vendor version : 17.0.3+7-LTS
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 17.0.3+7-LTS
JVM info           : mixed mode, sharing
OS name            : Mac OS X
OS version         : 12.0.1


Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access annotation property public abstract boolean jdk.internal.util.random.RandomSupport$RandomGeneratorProperties.isStochastic()
    at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.beforeEach(MockitoExtension.java:153)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:162)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:129)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Set.forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)" because the return value of "org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext$Store.remove(Object, java.lang.Class)" is null
        at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.afterEach(MockitoExtension.java:184)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachCallbacks$12(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:257)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:273)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$14(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:273)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:272)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:256)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:141)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class java.util.Random.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 17
JVM vendor name    : Azul Systems, Inc.
JVM vendor version : 17.0.3+7-LTS
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 17.0.3+7-LTS
JVM info           : mixed mode, sharing
OS name            : Mac OS X
OS version         : 12.0.1


Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access annotation property public abstract boolean jdk.internal.util.random.RandomSupport$RandomGeneratorProperties.isStochastic()
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access annotation property public abstract boolean jdk.internal.util.random.RandomSupport$RandomGeneratorProperties.isStochastic()
    at net.bytebuddy.description.annotation.AnnotationDescription$ForLoadedAnnotation.getValue(AnnotationDescription.java:824)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$Default.handle(AnnotationAppender.java:314)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$Default.doAppend(AnnotationAppender.java:377)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$Default.append(AnnotationAppender.java:354)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.TypeAttributeAppender$ForInstrumentedType.apply(TypeAttributeAppender.java:93)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForCreation.create(TypeWriter.java:5916)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:2213)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:232)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:204)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3668)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:288)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.lambda$mockClass$0(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:47)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:168)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:399)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:190)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:410)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:40)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:77)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:42)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:53)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:96)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1965)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.SpyAnnotationEngine.spyNewInstance(SpyAnnotationEngine.java:130)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.SpyAnnotationEngine.process(SpyAnnotationEngine.java:70)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:75)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:47)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:81)
    at org.mockito.internal.framework.DefaultMockitoSession.<init>(DefaultMockitoSession.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.session.DefaultMockitoSessionBuilder.startMocking(DefaultMockitoSessionBuilder.java:83)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class net.bytebuddy.description.annotation.AnnotationDescription$ForLoadedAnnotation cannot access interface jdk.internal.util.random.RandomSupport$RandomGeneratorProperties (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.util.random to unnamed module @a803f94
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:560)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.annotation.AnnotationDescription$ForLoadedAnnotation.getValue(AnnotationDescription.java:803)
    ... 83 more
```

Looking up maven dependency tree, below is the versions of spring, mockito...

```
spring-boot-starter-test: 2.7.1
mockito-core: 4.5.1
byte-buddy: 1.12.11 (managed from 1.12.9)
```

Edit1: Adding the test code below.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ChallengeGeneratorServiceTest {

  private ChallengeGeneratorService challengeGeneratorService;

  @Spy
  private Random random;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    challengeGeneratorService = new ChallengeGeneratorServiceImpl(random);
  }

  @Test
  public void generateRandomFactorIsBetweenExpectedLimits() {
    // 89 is max - min range
    given(random.nextInt(89)).willReturn(20, 30);

    // when we generate a challenge
    Challenge challenge = challengeGeneratorService.randomChallenge();

    // then the challenge contains factors as expected
    then(challenge).isEqualTo(new Challenge(31, 41));
  }

}
```

Note: I understand similar question have been answered before but somehow I couldn't derive the correct solution to fix my case.

Edit2: This turns out to be a duplicate question. [mockito-can-not-mock-random-in-java-17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70993863/mockito-can-not-mock-random-in-java-17) solves this.

Comment: Can you show the field that you're using `@Spy` for?

Comment: Related problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70993863/19322223

Comment: @Rob I have updated the question with the code used.

Comment: @Haoliang I missed out on this. Hopefully that works. Will close this as duplicate in that case. Thanks. Edit: The solution there does work. Thanks a lot.